# DynamoDB: Can't use contains in sort key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

I believe I've found a bug in DynamoDB using PartiQL.

Given this table:

```
  name      = "my-table"
  hash_key  = "user_id"
  range_key = "sites"

  attributes = [
    { name = "user_id", type = "S" },
    { name = "sites", type = "S" },
  ]

  global_secondary_indexes = [
    {
      name            = "by-user-id-and-sites-global-index"
      hash_key        = "user_id"
      range_key       = "sites"
      projection_type = "ALL"
    },
  ]
```

For some `user_ids`, the following PartiQL SELECT Statement works, for others doesn't (returns no results):

```
SELECT * FROM "my-table"."by-user-id-and-sites-global-index" WHERE "user_id" = '91f66b0e-1565-431b-aa4a-5db301af9510' AND contains("sites", '6211be1c-472f-4dff-83b5-5e9418106ff3')
```

I also tried with `begins_with` and it always works, however I explicitly need to use `contains` in the sort key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug. PartiQL is built on top of the core DynamoDB APIs, so whichever syntax you use dictates the core DynamoDB API being called.

In your case you're using a Query under the hood, as you provide the partition key and a condition on the sort key, however, the contains operator is not a valid sort key expression. Only these conditions can be used:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html

For some reason your table and index share the same primary key?

If you want to use contains on the sort key, you would need an index where that attribute is not a key.

Comment: The table and index don't share the same hash key.
Your explanation makes total sense, I think that if I use `begins_with` then it does a Query under the hood, but if I use `contains` it will do a Scan, and in that case it technically is only Filtering in a single page, so I need to iterate through all pages.
Appreciate your feedback on this!